# Tidy way to check for Null (Nothing) Variables in nested classes

Tags: .net, vb.net, if-statement, null, nullreferenceexception

I would like to take some action if the `Boolean` value `FormFoo.Bar.Baz.Quux` exists and is `True`. However, `Bar` and `Baz` are members of class type and might be `Nothing` (in which case, the action should not be taken).

I currently have the following code but it is ugly:

```
If (Not FormFoo.Bar Is Nothing) AndAlso (Not FormFoo.Bar.Baz Is Nothing) AndAlso FormFoo.Bar.Baz.Quux Then
    DoSomething()
End If
```

Is there an alternative way to do this test that is more readable?

Comment: If the number of elements in the condition is too big (3 doesn't sound too big), I would personally rely on a loop + collection including all the properties to check (and perform the checks right away or rely on a function in case of being more complicated); although all this is not exactly applicable here. In any case, I don't think that this is too relevant; if else statements are very quick and its readability is quite good.

Comment: any reason for downvotes? (not being confrontational, but would like to know how the question could be improved)

Comment: I think that your question is not exactly off-topic but almost; in the sense that it doesn't provide relevant-for-future-readers insights. As said in my comment above, I don't think that any programmer should spend even 1 second on analysing so irrelevant issues. This is almost playing with the code, using it as a mere distraction when you are bored. I don't think that this is what SO is about. I did downvote your question when it was +2 because, in my opinion, it was over-rated (+ you got a net reputation gain anyway +20-2 = +18).

Comment: @varocarbas ok, thanks for explaining. I like to write tidy code, in my experience the simpler a piece of code is, the easier it is to read and maintain. In fact this code is going to appear in a public code sample I want to publish as a demonstration. BTW, [voting to balance is discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74666/is-voting-to-balance-in-the-spirit-of-the-site)

Comment: It is a matter of personal taste (for example: I am not precisely a fan of writing too small codes). In any case, I always try to think in what is best for SO as a whole when doing things like down-/up-voting. That's why it wasn't motivated by my personal taste, but by my understanding of what most of SO visitors are looking for: a reliable enough picture of what is best. When programming, the pure aesthetical (taste-based) aspects seem completely secondary to me: firstly, working; secondly, doing it quickly/efficiently; and lastly other issues.

Comment: PS: good reference, but I don't agree with it (Meta posts are not law, but opinable guidelines). If I like a question/answer but it has already many votes (more than what I consider worthy in that case), I don't upvote it. Equivalently, with downvotes. The whole point of the voting system is helping people to find out what is relevant/irrelevant more or less easily. Voting regardless of the previous votes avoids such a goal to be fulfilled. I am always as objective as possible when voting (i.e., don't care about the asker/answerer), but do consider previous votes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Visual Studio 2015 you can make use of the [Null-Propagating operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/magazine/dn890368.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to do this:

```
If FormFoo.Bar?.Baz?.Quux Then
    ' If branch taken only if Bar and Baz are non-null AND Quux is True
    DoSomething()
End If
```

Alternatively I suppose you could check for a `NullReferenceExceptions` but that is a bit messy and I don't encourage throwing exceptions in normal code operation:

```
Try
    If FormFoo.Bar.Baz.Quux Then
        DoSomething()
    End If
Catch ex As NullReferenceException
    'ignore null reference exceptions
End Try
```

Other than that, you could refactor the code into a separate function, which might even make it more readable:

```
If DoINeedToDoSomething() Then
    DoSomething()
End If

Private Function DoINeedToDoSomething() As Boolean
    'return false is any object is null/nothing
    If FormFoo.Bar Is Nothing OrElse FormFoo.Bar.Baz Is Nothing Then Return False
    'object are not null so return the value of the boolean
    Return FormFoo.Bar.Baz.Quux
End Function
```

Note that your original code can be tidied a little by making use of `IsNot` - which is the recommended standard by Microsoft:

```
If (FormFoo.Bar IsNot Nothing) AndAlso (FormFoo.Bar.Baz IsNot Nothing) AndAlso FormFoo.Bar.Baz.Quux Then
    DoSomething()
End If
```

Comment: I would also insert a line break after the `AndAlso` to prevent horizontal scrolling: `If FormFoo.Bar IsNot Nothing AndAlso
            FormFoo.Bar.Baz IsNot Nothing AndAlso
            FormFoo.Bar.Baz.Quux Then
            DoSomething()
        End If`